# Is there a way to have a nested loop with variable iterations

Tags: shell, loops, nested-loops, scp

I'm trying to extract a series of files from a multiple folders and put them onto a different server, the problem is that each folder has a different number of sub-folders which contain the files I want.

I've tried a variation of nested loops with a function describing the range, but that doesn't seem to be working as it instead prints the for-loop range function, and placing `$( FUNCTION )` around it doesn't seem to work either.

Here is my code so far:

```
for i in $(cat File_with_first_folder_names.txt)
    do  

for x in {1..$(test=$(du -hd1 ${i}/Folder/bins/ | wc -l) | echo "$((test - 1))")}
    do

    scp $i/Folder/bins/bin.${x}/genes.faa server:/path/to/destination/${i}_${x}_genes.faa

    done

done
```

And this doesn't work either:

```
for i in $(cat File_with_first_folder_names.txt)
    do  
    
    for x in $({1..$(test=$(du -hd1 ${i}/Folder/bins/ | wc -l) | echo "$((test - 1))")})
        do
    
        scp $i/Folder/bins/bin.${x}/genes.faa server:/path/to/destination/${i}_${x}_genes.faa
    
        done
    
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. It requires the use of eval to execute the for loop argument that was only printed. So the final code would look like this:

```
for i in $(cat File_with_first_folder_names.txt)
do


for x in $(eval echo "{1..$(test=$(du -hd1 ${i}/Folder/bins/ | wc -l) | echo "$((test - 1))")}")
    do

    scp $i/Folder/bins/bin.${x}/genes.faa server:/path/to/destination/${i}_${x}_genes.faa

    done

done
```